# What are the different methods of Aura cleaning?

Tags: meditation, chakras

As far as I know few methods to clean our Aura are :

- Keep the body clean(Abhyanga snana).
- Wind bath.
- Mud bath.
- Fire bath.
- Eat Veggies.
- Thought , Word and Deed have to be in harmony channelised towards Dharma.

[Aura cleansing by Sadhguru Jaggu Vasudev](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oon-2iB8e8k)

Are there any other methods which are having reference in our scripts?

If above given methods are not correct then do explain with references.

Comment: these are all secondary and not primary. The real cleaning is done by purity of the mind. Make the mind pure. The mind is made pure primarily through japa and meditation, constant thinking of the Lord. No times are set, no rites are needful for chanting of His name. Think of Him and He Himself will come and clean your aura - no need for mud baths!!

Comment: @ swami vishwananda Thank you
I totally agree your view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking about the different types of baths then Shastras do mention about the **5** kinds of them viz:

1)Agneya(fiery) 2)Varuna(water bath) 3)Braahma (bathing using Vedic mantras) 4)Vaayavya(windy) & 5)Divya (Celestial holy bath).

> 9.*Snaanaani Panchapunyaani Kirtitaani Manishibhihi,Agneyam Varunam Braahmam Vyavyam Divyameva cha*- The learned have declared five kinds of bathing to purificatory : the Agneya or fiery bathing, the Varuna or the watery bathing, the
>   Brahma or Vedic bathing, the VAyavya or windy bathing, and the Divya
>   or the celestial bathing.(Parashara Smriti Chapter 12)

[image]

**Agneya** is smearing the body with holy ash(Vasma or Vibhuti).

**Varuna** is bathing with water,plunging into water.

**Braahma** is bathing with marjana mantras like "Om apohistha Mayo bHuba.."

**Vaayavya** is bathing  with the dust raised by the hoofs of the cows

**Divya** is bathing in rain water when there are rains and sunlight simultaneously.

> 10 — 11. The Agneya bathing consists in bathing with ashes ; the
>   Varuna is plunging into the water ; the Brahma consists in reciting
>   the verse ' apohishta, &c. ;' the Vayavya is bathing with the dust
>   raised by the hoof of a cow ; but the celestial bathing takes place
>   when one is drenched with, rain-water, the rain coming down while the
>   sun is shining. This kind of bathing is of equal efficacy with the
>   bathing in the river Ganga

However,if you are talking about Chakra cleansing, then that is accomplished by meditation(coupled with  repetitions of appropriate beejams like Lam,Ram,Vam,Yam etc) as taught by the teacher.

In general,chittasuddhi is obtained by constantly repeating the Ishta mantra (the one received from the Guru) & nadishuddi by the practice of pranayama.

Comment: Thanks, can you share more information on Aura cleansing, Chakra cleansing with reference to texts?

Comment: I'm not sure but Hatha Yoga Pradipika,Bheranda Samhita mite have the relevant details.

Comment: @ Rickross, Thanks
I go with chittasuddhi and meditation